# keyboard shortcut csv file column header width autofit in excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, csv, export-to-csv

[image: My question]

Comment: Well that's one way to be sure no one improves (edits) your question.

Comment: took me a while to figure out what you meant. I am not stack savvy yet to tinker with html tags etc. I just threw my question in word with screenshots then just put the screenshot from word into stack while posting the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using scripting of any sort to open the CSV in Excel, one possibility is to simply autosize all columns to fit after opening the file:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:I").AutoFit
```

Of course, change `I` to the appropriate column needed.

Reference: [AutoFit Method [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223697%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: thats a good tip. thanks. Is there some setting in excel where I can say "any time you open a csv file, just autofit all columns". I will check on this as well.

Comment: I googled for "How to Autofit column Width in Excel". Basically used excel to record a macro to autofit all columns and assigned this macro to a keybd shortcut. Now I open the csv file and hit a hotkey and my job is done.

Comment: even better. No macro needed. Open the csv file in excel. Press ctrl a to select all, then keep ALT pressed and type OCA (Alt O C A). Works like a charm.

Comment: @user666490 I could have told you about the menu-driven method you describe, but I thought you were asking a programming question. :)

Comment: Yes. Originally my question was programming based. At the time of creating my csv file using c#/streamwriter I wanted to create the csv file in such a way that it opened up autofitted whether in notepad or excel. It appears I have to either create a xlsx/xls file using libraries like epplus or do the autofit using shortcuts. thanks

Comment: @Gullu, another really quick shortcut:  click the 'select all' button at the top-left of the sheet.  double-click the divider between A and B column headers.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are raw text data without any display information.  The short answer is "you can't."

The longer answer is you can't do it with CSV files.  However, you can save the file as a different format that includes display information along with the data (eg, XLS, or even HTML tables imported into Excel).  This might not even be an issue if the CSV requirement is for processing data through another program.

Comment: bummer. Assuming I need to save the csv as xls so it shows up as I want when opened in excel what do I need to get started. Any pointers will help. thanks